# Prove that dim$($Ker$(A^n))$ is odd for all $n$ sufficiently large

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the following problem:

Let $A$ be a matrix of $101$ by $101$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$, such that trace$(A^n)=0$ for all $n$ positive integer. Prove that dim$($Ker$(A^n))$ is odd for all $n$ sufficiently large.

Thank you by some helps.

Comment: could you better explain the entries of $A$.

Comment: the entries of $A$ are $0$ or $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Q\in Z_2[X]$ be a polynomial such that $Q(A)$ is a projector onto the kernel of $A^k$. Then $ tr (Q(A))=0$ is the dimension of $\ker A^k$  modulo 2.

To construct $Q$, let $P$ the minimal polynomial of $A$ and write $P=X^kQ$, $Q$ prime to $X$.

Replacing $A$ by $A^k$ we may assume that $k=1$.

Then $Q= XQ'+1$

As $AQ(A)=0$, $Im(Q(A))\subset \ker (A)$. And if $x\in ker A, Q(A)(x)=x$, $Q$ is the desired polynomial

Comment: Excuse me!. But why the $tr(Q(A))=0$ is the dimension of $Ker(A^k)$ mod $2$ ?. By other hand, I know that $A$ has at least a eigenvalue equal to zero, so thus minimal polynomial is of the form $P=X^m Q$ some $m$, is correct this?.

Comment: What is the trace of a projector ?

Comment: Thomas. The trace of projector is rank of it. Then using that $$\dim(\mathbb{F}_{2}^{101})=\dim(Ker(A^k))+rank(A^k))=\dim(Ker(A^k)) \, mod\, 2$$.

Comment: This last equation implies that $\dim(ker(A^k))$ is odd.

Comment: And what was your question ?

Comment: My question, is over the construction of $Q$, for my is not clearly. You can be more explicit please.